# Дубли в словаре Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Имеется словарь с дублями примерно такой структуры:

```py
{'Имя1 Фамилия1': {'email': 'email',
                      'organisation': '',
                      'phone': '',
                      'position': 'position'},
 'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчество1': {'email': '',
                                'organisation': 'organisation',
                                'phone': 'phone',
                                'position': ''}}
```

Мне нужно соединить его таким образом, чтобы получилось:

```py
{'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчество1': {'email': 'email',
                             'organisation': 'organisation',
                             'phone': 'phone',
                             'position': 'position'}}
```

Как это можно было бы сделать?

Comment: Можно через defaultdict, можно через multidict смотря зачем это

Comment: Но лучше имя переместить в значение

Comment: Это нужно для сокращения дублей в словаре. К сожалению при простом использовании update и pop теряются данные

Comment: Добавьте кода, не понятно что у вас не получается

Comment: К сожалению, в этом и проблема. Совершенно не могу представить, как выстроить логику здесь

Comment: У вас в словаре так и записано "Иван Иванов Иванович"?

Comment: поясните главное:  1). ваш ключ ` 'Имя1 Фамилия1' `  и  `  'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчество1'  `  различаются только на отчество через пробнл или возможны ситуации  `  'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчес'  ` .   другими словами   -  достаточно найти хоть один символ после второго пробела?                  2)  не бывает случаев когда есть только имя?

Comment: ваша задача решается в три приема.  1) найти пары (тройки, ...)  почти одинаковых ключей и  2) собрать результирующий комплект используя максимальное значение по каждому подключу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение "в лоб", чем-то напоминающее [`LEFT OUTER JOIN (SQL)`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN) :

```py
from pprint import pprint
din = {'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчество1': {'email': '',
                                   'organisation': 'organisation3',
                                   'phone': 'phone3',
                                   'position': ''},
       'Имя1 Фамилия1': {'email': 'email1',
                         'organisation': '',
                         'phone': '',
                         'position': 'position1'},
       'Имя2 Фамилия2': {'email': '',
                         'organisation': 'organisation2',
                         'phone': 'phone2',
                         'position': ''},
        'Имя0': {'email': 'email0',
                 'organisation': 'org0',
                 'phone': 'phone0',
                 'position': 'pos0'}}
dout = dict()
for l in din:
    merged = False
    for r in din:
        if l < r:
            if r.startswith(l):
                dout[r] = dout.get(r, dict())
                for k in din[r]:
                    dout[r][k] = din[r][k] if din[r][k] else din[l].get(k, '')
                merged = True
    if not merged and l not in dout: dout[l] = din[l]
pprint(dout)
```

Результат:

```
{'Имя0': {'email': 'email0',
          'organisation': 'org0',
          'phone': 'phone0',
          'position': 'pos0'},
 'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчество1': {'email': 'email1',
                             'organisation': 'organisation3',
                             'phone': 'phone3',
                             'position': 'position1'},
 'Имя2 Фамилия2': {'email': '',
                   'organisation': 'organisation2',
                   'phone': 'phone2',
                   'position': ''}}
```

[Демо](https://rextester.com/ZVREPB78684).
Можно попробовать использовать возможности, предоставляемые модулем [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html).

Answer (score 0):

приведу вариант, несколько обобщенный. Он решает случаи, когда (вдруг) отчество бывает разной длины. Тогда более длинное ФИО считается правильным.  Тот же принцип применен и к остальным полям.

```
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import groupby

din = {
       'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчество1': {'email': '',
                                   'organisation': '',
                                   'phone': 'phone3',
                                   'position': ''},
       'Имя1 Фамилия1': {'email': 'email1',
                         'organisation': '',
                         'phone': '',
                         'position': 'position1'},
       'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчест': {'email': '',
                                   'organisation': 'organisation3',
                                   'phone': 'MSphone3',
                                   'position': ''},
       'Имя2 Фамилия2': {'email': '',
                         'organisation': 'organisation2',
                         'phone': 'phone2',
                         'position': ''},
        'Имя0': {'email': 'email0',
                 'organisation': 'org0',
                 'phone': 'phone0',
                 'position': 'pos0'}
        } 


    ordered_din = sorted(din.keys())  #собираем и сортируес ключи

    def FIO(text):   #для ключа - только имя и фамилия (без отчества)
        return text.rpartition(" ")[0]  if len(text.split(" "))==3  else text

    separ = " "
    for key, group in groupby(ordered_din, FIO):
        rez = list()
        if separ in key:   # работаем тольоко там, где есть Фамилия 
            rez = list(group)
            if len(rez) >1:
                long_key = rez.pop()  #отделяем из списка самый длинный ключ
                for key in rez:       # перебираем значения по остальным ключам
                    for subkey in din[long_key].keys():
                        if len(din[long_key][subkey]) < len(din[key][subkey]):
                            din[long_key][subkey] = din[key][subkey]
                    del din[key]
pprint(din)
```

дает на выходе:

```
{'Имя0': {'email': 'email0',
          'organisation': 'org0',
          'phone': 'phone0',
          'position': 'pos0'},
 'Имя1 Фамилия1 Отчество1': {'email': 'email1',
                             'organisation': 'organisation3',
                             'phone': 'MSphone3',
                             'position': 'position1'},
 'Имя2 Фамилия2': {'email': '',
                   'organisation': 'organisation2',
                   'phone': 'phone2',
                   'position': ''}}
```

Обращаю внимание, что `'phone'` присвоено самое длинное значение из существующих